# Css class name getting changed in html of aspx page

Tags: html, asp.net, css, menu

I'm working on aspx pages and i have asp.net Menu and CSS assigned to it.
But when I run the application the CSS class names get changed and its dynamically created as we see in controls inside "ContentPlaceHolder".

The code is

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu"
EnableViewState="False"  IncludeStyleBlock="False" Orientation="Horizontal">
 <DynamicItemTemplate>
      <%# Eval("Text") %>
 </DynamicItemTemplate>
 <Items>
    .
    .
    .
 </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

please check this Image what i get when i run this..

[image: Css Class creation]

I checked my application to know whether the Menu control is placed inside content placeholder or anything. But its not.

Do anyone know how to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you show your code please?

Comment: I have added it in the Question now. Please check it.

Answer (score 1):

class="menu ct100..." means that this element has two classes 1:menu and 2:ct100...
and nothing is wrong with it!the ct100... is generated by asp.net and if it is different any time you run the page it's up to asp.net component and if you dont like that try not to use this built in component, that i think you should do it.

by the way the only thing is changing when using master pages is client side id, that you can avoid this from happening by code below

```
<asp:TextBox ID="myId"  runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

set ClientIDMode to Static

Comment: Its not the ID its the ClassName... <asp:menu id="myid" CssClass="menu" ..... The "CssClass" is the thing which is getting changed.

Comment: sorry, but there is nothing wrong with the code, you have your class menu, and the one generated for you

Comment: This is what makes me confused. Why that class name is getting changed when im running it. If it was ID its ok, but this is css class name which should be static always.

Comment: why is that confusing!?did you use asp.net navigation?

Comment: Its confusing because the CssClass should not be changed when you run it. I have never seen a Css class name changing dynamically when its run. The ClientIDMode property also doesnt have anything to do with Class name of the css

Comment: I changed the clinetidmode.. but still it has the problem.

Comment: yes i know that is not your problem. i just tried to have a complete answer. if you are using asp.net navigation component it is not open source so i cant tell you what exactly going on, but it is not something bad!why you care about that?